# How to resolve the issue with reindexing process.Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, error, indexing

I have just created new products and try to view on the store i checked that a re-index process is pending so i tried to re-index but its giving me error as follows:

```
There was a problem with reindexing process.
```

I have tried to fixed it by clearing the cache and assign a base product category to store but still the problem presents.

Please any help on this.

Comment: There are few basic step at there, first all file from var/report,var/locks. Then  enable the  log setting  check the log when you will try to reindex

Answer (score 0):

You just need to start indexing with different way to get what is the error.

Try to create a file named `test.php`, Then add below code

```
< ?php
//Following 3 lines will load the magento admin environment.
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
$app = Mage::app('admin');
umask(0);

// to reindex the processes we require their ids
// for default magento there are 9 processes to reindex, numbered 1 to 9. 
$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9);

// Sometimes there are processes from our custom modules that also require reindexing
// We need to add those ids to our existing array of ids
// To know the id of process, just hover on each process in your
// admin panel-> System-> Index Management
// You will get a url : admin/process/some_id/......
// this id corresponds to the process

$ids = array(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,390,391,478);
foreach($ids as $id)
{
//load each process through its id
try
{
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($id);
$process->reindexAll();
echo "Indexing for Process ID # ".$id." Done<br />";
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}
?>
```

Then add the file on root and run it by entering `www.yourdomain.com/text.php` to the url.

Also if you have **ssh access** then run `php -f shell/indexer.php –reindex all` from root directory.

Using this way you can find what the actual problem is.

**Hope this will help you solve your problem**.

Comment: Indexing for Process ID # 1 Done

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= 'abs', ( - i.price), IF( = 'fixed', , ROUND(i.price * ( / 100), 4)))), 0) AS `' at line 1

Indexing for Process ID # 3 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 4 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 5 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 6 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 7 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 8 Done
Indexing for Process ID # 9 Done

I got this output.. what to do with it @Asish Hira